# Where is in ember.js a good place to init JS plugins?

Tags: plugins, ember.js

I want add the functionality of the [jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) into my app. I got a handlebar template and controller.
The plugin is initialized by typical jquery code

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json'
    ....
```

but I cannot figure aout where the place for that code. Should it be some controller-init callback or something? But I need to apply it to the element every time template is shown to the user, so it should be some onShow event or something like that?
Thank you!